# ssh to ngrok errors with Connection Refused on macbook

Tags: macos, ssh, ngrok

On my macbook, I'm unable to ssh into my ngrok instance, with the following error:

```
MacBook-Air:~ $ ssh -v USER@tcp://0.tcp.ap.ngrok.io -p 66666
OpenSSH_9.0p1, LibreSSL 3.3.6
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 21: include /etc/ssh/ssh_config.d/* matched no files
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 54: Applying options for *
debug1: resolve_canonicalize: hostname tcp://0.tcp.ap.ngrok.io is an unrecognised address
debug1: Authenticator provider $SSH_SK_PROVIDER did not resolve; disabling
debug1: Connecting to tcp://0.tcp.ap.ngrok.io port 66666.
ssh: connect to host tcp://0.tcp.ap.ngrok.io port 66666: Connection refused
```

whereas using the chrome ssh extension, I am able to ssh in. Is there any way to get more ssh debug so I can figure out what is going on?

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
ssh -vvv -p 66666 USER@0.tcp.ap.ngrok.io
```